# Apply Perl substitution between two delimiters within a string

Tags: r, matlab, perl

I'm trying to do some MATLAB to R conversion, and the existing scripts only get me so far. One thing missing is the handling of matrices.

I'd like to use Perl to go from:

```
bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]
```

to:

```
bbox <- c(minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ)
```

Replacing `=` with `<-`, and `[]` with `()` is easy, but a global search/replace on spaces to commas won't work.

How can I confine the operation to between the square brackets?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: This question should not be tagged with *R* or *MATLAB*. Knowledge of those languages is neither necessary nor helpful in providing a solution.

Comment: @Borodin - I disagree.  If you are converting languages, wouldn't a knowledge of those syntaxes be required to do that?

Comment: @RichScriven: As I commented below, the problem is how to use Perl to convert spaces to commas within a string, but "confine the operation to between the [ & ]?". Not even minimal knowledge of R is required for that simple task.

Comment: Literal translations produce inferior code. Don't claim R is inefficient if the R code is slower than the original Matlab code.

Comment: @tranzmatt  In the light of the exchanges, I'd like to pitch in.  Translating code correctly is very difficult and if there are good existing tools that'd be best.  However, if you are going to process the file(s) yourself, from major languages I'd suggest to use Perl or Python or C++, in no particular order. There is Ruby as well, and there are others, but MATLAB or R would be an awkward choice for this (unless these are the languages you know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach to substituting just the spaces within the brackets:

```
> tmp <- "bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]"
> 
> gsub(" +(?=[^\\[]+\\])", ',', tmp, perl=TRUE)
[1] "bbox = [minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ]"
```

This uses the Perl look-ahead syntax to say match 1 or more spaces, but only if followed by 1 or more character other than `[` followed by a `]`.  The spaces before the first `[` or after the `]` will not match because the look-ahead part fails.

This will replace a space between `[` and the first variable name or if you have multiple spaces between the last variable name and `]`:

```
> tmp <- "bbox = [  minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ  ]"
> gsub(" +(?=[^\\[]+\\])", ',', tmp, perl=TRUE)
[1] "bbox = [,minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ, ]"
```

But if that is an issue then the regex can be modified:

```
> tmp <- "bbox = [  minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ  ]"
> 
> gsub("(?<![\\[ ]) +(?=[^ ])(?=[^\\[]+\\])", ',', tmp, perl=TRUE)
[1] "bbox = [  minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ  ]"
```

Now the spaces matched cannot be immediately preceded by `[` or a space and have to have at least one none space after them.

This approach has the regex engine going over the area between `[` and `]` several times, so may be slower than pulling out the section between brackets and doing the substitution on just that section as suggested by others.

Answer (score 8):

Two alternative approaches with R:

**1)** Using only `gsub`:

```
strng <- 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]'

strng <- gsub('\\s', ',', strng)
strng <- gsub(',=,', ' <- ', strng)
strng <- gsub('\\[', 'c(', strng)
strng <- gsub('\\]', ')', strng)
```

**2)** Using `chartr` and `gsub`:

```
strng <- chartr(' []',',()', strng)
strng <- gsub(',=,', ' <- c', strng)
```

or in a single line:

```
gsub(',=,', ' <- c', chartr(' []',',()',strng))
```

which both give:

```
> strng
[1] "bbox <- c(minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ)"
```

Explanation:

- With the `gsub`-function (format: `gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ...)`; see `?gsub` for the remaining parameters) you can replace speciic characters (or charactersets).
- With the `chartr`-function (format: `chartr(old, new, x)`) you can translate each character in `x` that is specified in `old` to the corresponding character specified in `new`.

If the string has leading or trailing spaces (as said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381802/apply-perl-substitution-between-two-delimiters-within-a-string/41382346?noredirect=1#comment70312213_41382346)), you should start both options with `strng <- trimws(strng)` first.

---

Notes:

1. Converting code from one language to another with regular expressions might not be the right way to go as you will highly probably run into edge-cases. Rewriting your code in R will require a higher time investment, but worth the trouble if you are going to switch to R.
2. Some extra resources:

   - A [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [script](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-October/025532.html) written by Paul Gilbert that converts Matlab code to R code.
   - A [Matlab / R reference guide](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf) by David Hiebeler

Comment: An interesting way to do it in R.  I might be better off hacking the mat2r script than trying to do it in perl?

Comment: @tranzmatt these approaches seem pretty straightforward to me

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: R is a language intended for statistical and graphical applications, and has only minimal text support. Why are you trying to use R to convert MATLAB to R?

Comment: @Borodin Why the downvote? OP asked for a method to go from one string to another. I provided two alternatives with R as the question was also labelled with [tag:r].

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: Had the request been to convert C to machine code using Perl, would you have offered a machine code solution?

Comment: @Borodin again: what is wrong with providing an alternative in R?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: Because the OP asked for it: *" I'd like to use perl to go from..."* and because they mention *"the existing scripts"*, which are presumably also in Perl. If you are recommending a wholesale rewrite into R, or even that part of the suite should be written in R instead of Perl, then you should say so in your answer and have a very good reason for it. Since the actual reason is that you don't Perl, I think you should have just stayed quiet. You even edited the subject line to remove *Perl*, which further hid the requirement.

Comment: The question is tagged R.  I see no problem in providing an R answer.

Comment: @RichScriven: When the question is clearly about using Perl to translate MATLAB to R, and ***R*** is tagged only because it is the destination language, I think it is perverse to use that as permission to avoid the OP's requirement. Even an *awk* or *sed* answer would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @Borodin - I don't understand why you are so upset about this.  The question is tagged with both R and Perl.  An R answer is here, and you can provide a Perl answer (which you've done), and we all live happily ever after.  Is it really that big of a deal?

Comment: Given that the OP already explicitly mentioned the `mat2r` script, which is written in R, in this comment thread he obviously doesn't have an issue using R. This has quickly approached needlessly pedantic and rather childish. Rather than attacking each other and getting into an edit battle, how about you **ask the OP for clarification** and not make assumptions? Text on the internet and all...

Comment: @excaza: I don't think any clarification is needed. The core question is *" I'd like to use perl to go from [MATLAB] to [R]"* which this doesn't solve. I would initially have written my answer, made my comments about the suitability of the R solutions, and left it at that, except that Mr Maximus has chosen to prevaricate.

Comment: @Borodin If you don't know [MATLAB] or [R], how could one possibly convert from one to the other? Furthermore: I removed *Perl* from the title as it was also tagged with *Perl*, as a result people from the [tag:perl] community would see it anyway.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: Ordinarily you would be correct, but the original message was clearly mistagged, and in this case the removal of *Perl* from the subject line makes it appear as if R or MATLAB solutions are viable. The problem is how to use Perl to convert spaces to commas within a string, but *"confine the operation to between the [ & ]?"*. Not even minimal knowledge of R is required for that task.

Comment: @excaza: I think the call to maturity applies principally to the downvoter of my perfectly-good answer. If you thought that nothing more should be said then why did you weigh in in the first place and become *"needlessly pedantic and rather childish"* yourself.

Comment: @Borodin If you'd like to continue hashing this out, you're welcome to [find me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza).

Comment: @Borodin if the OP accepts your answer, it will be pushed to the top. By what you're saying, this should happen anyways as he's looking for a Perl solution. Having alternatives doesn't hurt anybody. In fact it may help somebody in the future, so let's just forget about the imaginary unicorn points for a moment, or drop the principle you're fighting so hard for. I don't know why I'm even commenting, this whole mess will hopefully be cleaned up by a mod.

Comment: @Borodin OP wants to translate some Matlab code to R code and likes to do that with Perl. This doesn't mean that giving an alternative in the target language is wrong. OP's problem can be solved in Perl, R and Matlab; which is reflected in the given answers. As **ballBreaker** said: *"Having alternatives doesn't hurt anybody."*

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus  Huh ... what an exchange.  I have to say,  proposing a solution with either MATLAB or R for this _is_ in fact a bit wrong -- it proposes a wrong tool for the job.  There is a question of translating a file to another. Good tools? Perl, Python ... even C++ would be far, far better than either R or MATLAB. There is of course nothing wrong in posting (possibly interesting) code, but it is misleading.

Comment: Actually, I was happy to see the R version too as I'm still learning how to program R.   Alas, and I partially blame myself for this, the R method provided here doesn't seem to account for leading spaces in the code.  So if the matlab original text has leading spaces (indented):

     bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]

became

,,,,,bbox <- c(minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ)

Comment: @tranzmatt to deal with leading/trailing spaces, you can use the `trimws` function in R, which removes leading & trailing spaces; you can do that by doing `strng <- trimws(strng)` before the steps I presented in the answer (added it to the answer as well now)

Answer (score 3):

you could use a capture expression to grab the `sub_string` inside of the brackets and manipulate it separately:

```
string <- "bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]"

sub_string <- gsub(".*(\\[.*\\])", "\\1", string)
sub_string <- gsub(" ", ",", sub_string)
sub_string <- gsub("\\[", "c(", sub_string)
sub_string <- gsub("\\]", ")", sub_string)

final <- gsub("=", "<-", string)
final <- gsub("\\[.*", sub_string, final)
final
[1] "bbox <- c(minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ)"
```

Comment: An interesting way to do it in R.  I might be better off hacking the mat2r script than trying to do it in perl?

Comment: @NathanDay: R is a language intended for statistical and graphical application, and has only minimal text support. Why are you trying to use R to convert MATLAB to R?

Comment: Someone created a matconv library with the mat2r function.  It does some of the basic, but not all like handling syntax on vectors/matrices.  Originally, I thought perl might be quicker, but now I'm thinking R to expand the library (and make it available to others), plus force me to learn R more.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether the answers so far have answered your question. To me, you seem to want a *Perl* solution to converting *MATLAB* code to *R* code. Is that right?

I would generally use an *expression substitution* with the `/e` modifier, together with another *non-destructive substitution* for the replacement, which *returns* the result of the substitution instead of altering the object string directly

This program demonstrates the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ];';

$s =~ s{ \[ \s* \K ( .+? ) (?= \s* \] ) }{ $1 =~ s/\s+/,/gr }ex;

say $s;
```

#### output

```
bbox = [minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ];
```

An alternative way would be to use the fact that `substr` can act as an *lvalue* and so can be modified. This requires the `@-` and `@+` built-in arrays, which contain the offset of the start and end of the overall match in `$-[0]` and `$=[0]` and the starts and ends of the nth capture in `$-[n]` and `$+[n]` etc. where `n` is one or more

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ];';

if ( $s =~ / \[ \s* ( .+? ) \s* \] /x ) {
    substr($s, $-[1], $+[1]-$-[1]) =~ s/\s+/,/g;
}

say $s;
```

The output is identical to that of the previous code sample

Answer (score 2):

**1**) Using only `mgsub` from `qdap` and `sub` in a single line

```
library(qdap)
sub(", <-,", " <- ", mgsub(c("=", "[", "]", " "), c("<-", "c(", ")", ", "), strng))
#[1] "bbox <-  c(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ)"
```

---

**2**) Using only `base R`

```
gsub("\\s+", ", ", sub("\\s*=\\s+\\[([^]]+)\\]", "<-c(\\1)", strng))
#[1] "bbox<-c(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ)"
```

NOTE: Both of these solutions are single line code.

#### data

```
strng <- 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]'
```

Comment: An interesting way to do it in R.  I might be better off hacking the mat2r script than trying to do it in perl?

Comment: @akrun: R is a language intended for statistics and graphics, and has only minimal text support. Why are you trying to use R to convert MATLAB to R?

Comment: @akrun: I have downvoted all of the R solutions as being contrary to the question. I am sorry that you have been misled.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a MATLAB [regexp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) solution:

The basic regex:

```
str = 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]';

str = regexprep(str, '(?<!,)\s+(?=[^\\\[\]]*\])', ', ');
str = regexprep(str, '\[', 'c(');
str = regexprep(str, '\]', ')');
str = regexprep(str, '\=', '<-');
```

The [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/X94mg8/2) looks for any whitespace in the string that does not have a closing bracket following it or a comma preceding it. The remaining lines should be self-explanatory, but do note that they are very greedy implementations so they could negatively impact other portions of the code.

MATLAB isn't the greatest at file IO so modifying the file in-place won't be the most elegant thing in the world. One quick approach is to read the entire file into memory, perform the replacement(s), and then write it back to the file.

A naive example:

```
function MATLABarrays2R_sorta(filepath)
% Pipe the output of type to a string so we can perform the regex
evalcstr = sprintf('type(''%s'')', filepath);
mymcode = evalc(evalcstr);

% Regex can operate on cell arrays natively, so split now to ease writing
% later
mymcode = strsplit(mymcode, '\n', 'CollapseDelimiters', 0)';

myrcode = regexprep(mymcode, '(?<!,)\s+(?=[^\\\[\]]*\])', ', ');
myrcode = regexprep(myrcode, '\[', 'c(');
myrcode = regexprep(myrcode, '\]', ')');
myrcode = regexprep(myrcode, '\=', '<-');

% Write the file
[pathname, filename] = fileparts(filepath);
fID = fopen(fullfile(pathname, [filename '.r']), 'w');
for ii = 1:length(mymcode)
    fprintf(fID, '%s\n', myrcode{ii});
end
fclose(fID);
end
```

And a toy example:

```
% MATLAB
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
minX = 1;
minY = 2;
abcd = 3;
ABCD = 4;
B = [minX minY abcd ABCD];

% R
% See, greedy regex isn't great!
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
minX <- 1;
minY <- 2;
abcd <- 3;
ABCD <- 4;
B <- c(minX, minY, abcd, ABCD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Translating code correctly is very difficult.

You do have a regex based solution for the shown example. Here is an approach that parses a line into tokens and processes them. It can be developed further, if needed.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'bbox = [minX maxX minY maxY minZ maxZ]';

# Break by (any amount of any) whitespace. Then process and join as suitable
my @terms = split ' ', $str;

my $res;
for (@terms) 
{
    if (/=/) { $res .= '<-' }   # Translate = if found,
    else     { $res .= $_;  }   # or copy the term

    # Add comma for terms in '[' to ']' range, except for the last, with ']'
    # Outside of the range restore the space
    if (/^\[/ .. /]$/) { $res .= ',' unless /]$/ }
    else               { $res .= ' '             }
}

print "$res\n";
```

This prints the line   `bbox <- [minX,maxX,minY,maxY,minZ,maxZ]`

We break the string up by whitespace, then go term-by-term and change and join them as needed. This is where a more rounded analysis can be added as needed.

What may need a comment is the `..` [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). It returns a true/false and *maintains its state*. So once a term matches `/^\[/` it turns true and stays true until a term matches `/]$/`. It is normally used to identify a range of lines when processing a file, and also to make ranges of values, like `1..4` and `'a'..'z'`. Here we use it with the array of terms.

However, there is a whole lot more.

- Statements in MATLAB can be on the same line, separated by `;`.  The code above won't work for it, since `/]$/` is the last thing in the string (no `;` accounted for). This is fixed easily.
- But, matrices can also be given by slices of other vector objects, and this may involve indices with commas and spaces which *should not* be replaced by `,`.  This is not fixed easily.
- Matrices can be built in a number of other ways, for example dynamically.

With this approach you can develop the parser further. But the point is that it gets more and more difficult, as it is just hard to parse a programming language. Just a warning.

---

Given the stirred up discussion, I'd like to comment on the choice of *the tool for the job*.

This is firstly a text processing problem. I find the requested language (Perl) to be a good choice. The problem is yet harder given that the "text" is code, which makes the tool choice even more important.